# agent-state-info: 'hook failed: "config-changed" deploy wordpress using juju

Tags: juju, wordpress

I have one virtual machine on Windows Azure.
I have installed juju inside my virtual machine.
I want to deploy wordpress on my vm. I'm run on 64 bit machine

I've read this blog about step by step how to deploy wordpress:

https://juju.ubuntu.com/get-started/local

But i got error on my juju status like bellow :

```
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.12.0.1
    dns-name: 10.0.3.1
    instance-id: localhost
    series: precise
  "1":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.12.0.1
    instance-id: azureuser-local-machine-1
    instance-state: missing
    series: precise
  "2":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.12.0.1
    instance-id: azureuser-local-machine-2
    instance-state: missing
    series: precise
services:
  mysql:
    charm: cs:precise/mysql-27
    exposed: false
    relations:
      cluster:
      - mysql
      db:
      - wordpress
    units:
      mysql/0:
        agent-state: error
        agent-state-info: 'hook failed: "config-changed"'
        agent-version: 1.12.0.1
        machine: "1"
        public-address: 10.0.3.209
  wordpress:
    charm: cs:precise/wordpress-16
    exposed: true
    relations:
      db:
      - mysql
      loadbalancer:
      - wordpress
    units:
      wordpress/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.12.0.1
        machine: "2"
        public-address: 10.0.3.174
```

Then when i try to access public address which have ip 10.0.3.174 i got bad gateway.

On juju status i founded :

```
 units:
          mysql/0:
            agent-state: error
            agent-state-info: 'hook failed: "config-changed"'
```

How to solve this error ?

Comment: Can you add the arch of the boxes to your question? 64-bit or 32-bit?

Comment: `10.0.3.174` isn't a routable IP address: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918 -- are you confident you should be able to route to that instance from the machine you're using to test?

Answer (score 1):

What you see is an error that occurred during the hook execution for MySQL's configuration changed hook. This typically occurs due to one a few things

- A charm bug
- Missing configuration options
- a "hiccup" during hook execution

To start you will need to collect some information about your currently executing operation in the debug logs. Under production environments (like aws, hpcloud, etc) you run `juju debug-log -n 500` however, since you're running the local provider this will be located in

```
$HOME/.juju/local/logs/unit-wordpress-0.log
$HOME/.juju/local/logs/unit-mysql-0.log
```

The format of the log files is fairly straight forward, and should you require additional help parsing them, upload it to paste.ubuntu.com and we can go through the logs either in #Juju on IRC or update the question.

Usually when an error is encountered due to corner cases, or race conditions, you can resolve the error and retry hook execution by running `juju resolved -r <service>/<unit>`

so in the example of your mysql hook failure, `juju resolved -r mysql/0` will re-run the failed hook and if it completes successfully, the service will continue deployment.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're attempting to deploy production services, I encourage you to follow the Azure docs instead of installing to a local provider on an Azure VPS by following the docs [here](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/config-azure.html)